# Is it possible to limit file references to a specific file storage?

Tags: typo3, fal

The setup is the following:
I client of mine wants to give users the possibility to select a background image for a page. For the sake of simplicity let's say we create a new field in the pages table and configure its TCA separately, so we are completely side-effect free.

Now comes the tricky part. The storage, the users should select images from for that field, should be limited. So even if a backend user has admin rights and therefore access to all file storages and all files, users should only be able to select images from a given(configured) storage.

Is that somehow possible with a specific TCA configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to extend `FileBrowser` for this requirement. As you said nothing about visibility of the files, you could override `fileIsSelectableInFileList` in a subclass. So not exactly a pure TCA feature, but the implementation would allow a deeper integration of your ruleset.

```php
class LocalStorageBrowser extends FileBrowser {
    // users should only be able to select files from a specific driver
    protected function fileIsSelectableInFileList(FileInterface $file, array $imgInfo)
    {
        return $file->getStorage()->getDriver() instanceof LocalDriver;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Well, XClassing is always possible but not really my first choice. I hoped for a hidden configuration or such. :/

Comment: IMHO this is different from the traditional `hook into all FileBrowsers` XClassing since it's just a different Implentation for the FileBrowser and you can pin it just to your single field.